# Using replace function with VBA loses field code information

Tags: vba, search, powerpoint

I need to use VBA to replace part of a textbox in the template of a PowerPoint presentation. The same box contains a field code (is that the right phrase?) for the slide number.
When I execute the following code on every shape oSh in the template:
    `If oSh.HasTextFrame Then`
    `oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, searchString, newString)`
    `End If`
the information about the field code disappears - slide numbering is broken.
Example, if the shape had "this is slide number " followed by the slide number field code, then if I replace "this is slide number" with "slide", the text will show as "slide <#>".

When I use the PowerPoint "replace" function, the functionality is preserved (slide numbering still works). How is it different? And more importantly - how do I get the substring replaced without destroying the slide numbering?

Comment: Do a Macro recording on the Powerpoint Replace function and see what it records.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RBarryYoung - unfortunately you cannot record macros in PowerPoint in Office 2010 [see helpful MS suggestion](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/what-happened-to-the-macro-recorder-HA010338328.aspx). If anyone has an older version and wants to try, I would be grateful...

Comment: Wow!  Truly epic fail on Microsoft's part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When I use the PowerPoint "replace" function, the functionality is preserved (slide numbering still works). How is it different? And more importantly - how do I get the substring replaced without destroying the slide numbering?"

Doesn't the the first sentence answer the question posed in the second?  ;-)

For example, this snippet will do the replacement you ask for on each shape on each slide in the presentation:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "This is the slide number", "Slide"
    Next
Next
```

Using PPT's own Replace function solves a number of other problems as well ... it does a pretty good job of retaining mixed formatting, for example.

How's it different from the native VB/VBA Replace function?  App-specific functions like this can app-aware, ie, can special-case for features that the specific app supports.

Comment: Thank you for this solution - yes, I "answered my own question" in the first sentence, but could not figure out from the MS documentation how to call the PowerPoint replace function, rather than the VBA one. I was close - but you nailed it. This solution works perfectly - thanks a lot!

Comment: Great ... glad it helped.  BTW, in case it comes up, you can also create a TextRange from any portion of a larger textrange (see .Characters) and then use the Replace method on that.